# Validate very large .zip files (~12 GB) downlaoded from FTP using chilkat

Tags: c#, validation, zip, chilkat

I am using chilkat to download large .zip files from FTP server..
Files size usually goes around 12-13GB and after downloading I need to validate if file is not corrupt.

I've trying to use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip`

like this
`ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(path);
        bool isValidZip = zip.TestArchive(true, TestStrategy.FindFirstError, null);`

But validation take VERY long time or even crashes..

Is there  any quicker solutions ?

Comment: Are file hashes available on the FTP?

Comment: Not really.. 

Also, what I forgot to mention, is customer uploads to FTP and even after uploading it might be invalid so  I need to download it and to confirm, if it is valid file

Comment: I see. Do you have the possibility to have a Service running on the FTP? My first idea was to have a "Server-Side" validation and hashing. So basically, I'd split the FTP into an upload-Directory for Customers, then have the service validate and hash. If successful, move both to download directory. If validation fails, I'd move it to a special directory and notify some responsible user(group). Something like that, roughly.

Comment: to be honest I can do NOTHING on FTP side as its customer FTP and it's very hard to get anything done on that side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the customer is uploading to FTP, then maybe the customer can also upload a SHA256 hash.  For example, if the customer uploads x.zip, then compute the SHA256 of x.zip and also upload x.zip.sha256.    Then your application can download both x.zip and x.zip.sha256, and then use Chilkat.Crypt2.HashFile to hash the x.zip and check against x.zip.sha256.

If it's not possible to get an expected hash value, then you might first check the file size against what is on the server.  FTP servers can differ in how file information is provided.  Older servers will provide human-readable directory listings (LIST command) whereas newer servers (i.e. within the last 10 years) support MLSD.  Chilkat will use MLSD if possible.  The older FTP servers might provide in accurate (non-exact) file size information, whereas MLSD will be accurate.  You can call the Ftp2.Feat method to check to see if MLSD is supported.  If so, then you can first validate the size of the downloaded file.  If it's not the expected size, then you can skip any remaining validation because you already know it's invalid.  (You can set Ftp2.AutoGetSizeForProgress = true, and then Chilkat will not return a success status when MLSD is used and the total number of bytes downloaded is not equal to the expected download size.

Assuming the byte counts are equal, or if you can't get an accurate byte count, and you don't have an expected hash, then you can test to see if the zip is valid.  The 1st option is to call the Chilkat.Zip.OpenZip method.  Opening the .zip will walk the zip's local file headers and central directory headers.  Most errors will be caught if the .zip is corrupt.   The more comprehensive check is only possible by actually decompressing the data for each file within the zip -- and this is probably why SharpZipLib takes so long.  The only way to validate the compressed data is to actually do the decompression.  Corrupted bytes would likely cause the decompressor to encounter an impossible internal state, which is clearly corruption.  Also, the CRC-32 of the uncompressed data is stored in each local file header within the .zip.   Checking the CRC-32 requires decompression.   SharpZipLib is surely checking the CRC-32 (after it decompresses, and it's probably trying to decompress in memory and runs out of memory).   Chilkat.OpenZip does not check the CRC-32 because it's not decompressing.   You can call Chilkat.Unzip to unzip to the filesystem, and the act of unzipping also checks the CRC-32.

Anyway.. you might decide that checking the byte count and being able to call Chilkat.Zip.OpenZip successfully is sufficient for the validation check.

Otherwise, it's best to design the validation (using a parallel .sha256 file) in the system architecture if you're dealing with huge files..

Answer (score 0):

Some FTP servers have implemented hash commands (see [Appendix B](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bryan-ftp-hash-05.html)). Issue HELP on ftp prompt in order to get a list of all available commands and see if your server supports a hash command. Otherwise you must stick to zip testing.